# Is it possible in Angular2+ to get list of all components that implements some specific interface?

Tags: angular, typescript

Is it possible in Angular2+ to get, or inject list of all components that implements some specific interface? 
Specifically I need to reset state of all UI components on some event. My idea is to create an interface OnRest and when I need to reset them call reset() for all components that implement it. 
But I cannot find how to make Angular DI inject me a list of components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible: interface does not exist in runtime. Angular use TOKEN as key for injection, which means you need to provide all components which the same TOKEN...

I would create a service which expose an Observable. Components who subscribes to this observable will call `reset()` when a value is emitted.

Comment: yep, I did old style pre-RTTI - with explicit ResetUI service and implicit component registration.

Answer (score -1):

Not Possible. You will have to do it via a common service or shared service or @ngrx/store
to maintain that.